# C#/Visual Studio 2008 assigning "TopItem" property in "ListView" does not work

Tags: c#, listview, visual-studio-2008, properties

I am currently supporting a C# desktop application using Visual Studio 2008 (plan to upgrade soon).

I have a “List View” that gets populated with over 3000 items. Due to this large number of items, I created a “TextBox” in order for the user to start typing and have the matching “ListView” item scroll to the top of the “ListView”.

I have seen numerous posts on how this can be accomplished, the problem, the one that supposedly accomplishes this requirement does not work consistently. There are no “Groups” and property “ShowGroups” set to “false” for the "ListView". I read a “true” for the “ShowGroups” property may cause issues.

The code I found that should accomplish the task is as follows.

```
private void txtSearchCompany_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
  // Call FindItemWithText with the contents of the textbox.

   ListViewItem foundItem =
     lvCompany.FindItemWithText(txtSearchCompany.Text, true, 0, true);

   if (foundItem != null)
   {            
      lvCompany.TopItem = foundItem;
   }
 }
```

I have stepped through the code and I am baffled by the fact that the assignment statement only works occasionally.

For example, typing “02” into the “TextBox”, here is the break point at the assignment statement and the values before executing the assignment statement.

lvCompany.topItem {Text = "00000"}

foundItem         {Text = "02057"}

[Before assignment statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbHqc.png)

Now the values after the assignment statement.

lvCompany.topItem {Text = "01563"}

foundItem         {Text = "02057"}

[After assignment statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdmwK.png)

Why would “lvCompany.TopItem” be set to “01563”????

Here is the "ListView" after typing "02" in the "TextBox". The top item in the "ListView" does not have "02" in it. The "TopItem" is "01563".

[ListView display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WoEx.png)

Comment: is there enough rows underneath 02057 to put 02057 on the top of the visual listview? If not, 02057 will only move up if there are enough rows below it to fill the listview to the bottom of the visible view.

Comment: Yes, "02057" is row 311 of a total of 10,767 rows (more than I originally thought). The "ListView" has a fixed sized showing at most 20 rows. Therefore, my confusion on why "02057" does not scroll to the top and "01563" does.

Answer (score 0):

Pretend for a second that you have a listview with 4 rows visible. You populate that listview with 10 rows of information (1 through 10). Since there are 4 rows showing, the listview can only ever show 1 through 7 at the top because 7,8,9 and 10 are needed to show a full listview when there are more than 4 total rows in it. Since 8 cannot move to the top, the TopItem will still contain what is actually showing in the top of the listview which in this case would be 7. So 7, 8, 9 and 10 would all show 7 as the TopItem because the listview cannot move the rows up any further.

The same goes for if the listview is not full or has only 4 items to begin with. So taking that same listivew, let's populate it with only 4 items. For this, TopItem will always return 1 as there is no other rows below 4 to shift up.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense but, in my case there are more than enough rows to allow “TopItem” to be assigned the “02057” row and move that row to the top of the “ListView”. The “ListView” shows at most 20 rows and cannot be resized. Row “02057” is row 311 of 10,767 rows. Please see my previous comment. Thanks!